# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api-read.facebook.com:443

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, ssl, facebook-fql

Sometimes happens that is that I receive the error below, but sometimes it works fine. It happens when aplication is trying to use the graph api or when the graph api re-queries FQL.

For example:

```
select name, sex, pic_big, locale, email, birthday 
from user 
where uid = me();
```

Error:

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
   [result:protected] => Array
       (
           [error_code] => 35
           [error] => Array
               (
                   [message] => Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api-read.facebook.com:443
                   [type] => CurlException
               )

       )
```

I don't know what is about because it sometime work and sometime not. Has anyone idea what could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as I did sometime ago... change to api.facebook.com all your queries in the FB SDK.
Regards.

Comment: Is it safe? As i undesrtood apri-read is just for reading, wouldn't cause it any errors?

Comment: Sorry for the delay...as you may know it´s safe (may be slower but safe)